# Name of Art/Design Style with Black/White + Color Highlight

Tags: style-identification

I've seen a lot of art/design that uses minimalist design in black and white with a single color highlight. It's pretty much everywhere, from websites to home decor to clothing. Is there a name for this style?

Comment: When you use black and white, it's considered a monochromatic color scheme, but when you add a color, you can consider it an accent color.  Depending on the color, if it provides High-contrast, you could call it high-contrast monochromatic. I don't believe it has a specific name though, it's always referred to as "Monochromatic & accent"

Comment: Color use only is not enough to define a design style. It sound this could be anything, from Rococo to Streamline Moderne.

Comment: Picture can speak a thousand words. . .

Answer (score 1):

In a galaxy far, far away, a long, long time ago, this was known as "two colour printing", wherein it's (most often) black plus one colour, generally on white paper.

It was very popular (a long while back) because it was cheap and had little chance for bleed errors, and could be made to look quite good.

It soon became popular to use two colours without black.

Ironically, it's now more expensive and specialised in print, and generally called "spot colour" printing, now.

You can see some thoughts on extending this style here: https://designschool.canva.com/blog/monochromatic-colors/

The modern power of Photoshop type editng and desaturation, plus addition of one colour, can make for wonderfully powerful imagery.